# Can't send data to database when use filter-name contextConfigLocation spring securtiy

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I use restful web service with spring security to protect access url. Before i add spring security i can send data to database normally.I can't send data to database after i add some filler-name of spring security to web.xml like below:

-web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

After add some filler-name of spring security and than i use postman test send data to database it show error like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pivotal tc Runtime 3.1.1.RELEASE/8.0.23.A.RELEASE - Error report</title>
        <style type="text/css">H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}.line {height: 1px; background-color: #525D76; border: none;}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>HTTP Status 401 - Bad credentials</h1>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <p>
            <b>type</b> Status report
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>message</b>
            <u>Bad credentials</u>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>description</b>
            <u>This request requires HTTP authentication.</u>
        </p>
        <hr class="line">
            <h3>Pivotal tc Runtime 3.1.1.RELEASE/8.0.23.A.RELEASE</h3>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Please help me!

Comment: do you have any spring security config file?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the Security Configurations Please have a look below:

```
    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/url_pattern_of_your_rest_api**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
        <user name="username" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

This is a basic example, you can configure to look up user and authorization grants from database too.

```
<authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
          users-by-username-query=
            "select username,password, enabled from users where username=?"
          authorities-by-username-query=
            "select username, role from user_roles where username =?  " />
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

Since its a rest api it make perfect sense to have a custom AuthenticationEntryPointpoint, default behaviour is to redirect to a Login page which is of no use in a REST Api.

```
public class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    public void commence( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException ) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,"Unauthorized");
    }

}
```

You must configure the above as a bean and refer it in your `<http>` tag with  `entry-point-ref` attribute.